# nginx forwarding issue help, localhost works but not ip address

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

I have nginx website. When run locally, localhost everything works as planned. However when I deploy to a different server i get bad gateway.  In nginx I have this

```
server {
    listen 80;
     server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location ~ /api/(.*) {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;
      set $upstream api;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream:63415/api/$1;
  }
}
```

When I run locally, calls from the web app to localhost/api/company are routed to http://api:63415/api/$1, but when I deploy to a different server, I get bad gateway. 502 bad gateway http://10.99.9.23:8088/api/companies/, fyi 8088 is a port exposed by docker and maps to port 80 inside the nginx container. Here is how the front end service is defined.

```
private companiesUrl = '/api/companies/';  // URL to web API
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCompanies(): Promise<Array<Company>> {
     return this.http
        .get(this.companiesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json() as Company[];
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Can anyone help me to fix the nginx config. I am assuming this is the problem.